# Can't solve connection error Node.js and MySQL in Window

Tags: mysql, node.js

first of all, I work in Window.

I provide the necessary information (host, user, password, port, database) exactly, but it gives an error.

```
    code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
    errno: 1045,
    sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)",
    sqlState: '28000',
    fatal: true
```

I did many methods to solve this problem, but all failed. I don't know why it solves temporarily to re-install MySQL. but when I reboot my computer, there is an error again.
At once, I write my code, use versions, and try things.

### My code

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "123456",
    port: "3306",
    database: "study01"
    });
    console.log(connection);
    connection.connect();
    
    app.listen(app.get('port'), () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

### MySQL server & modules version

```
mysql server : 5.7.38
nodejs : 16.15.1
nodejs mysql : 2.18.1
nodejs express : 4.18.1
```

### I tried these things

- Changed password, created another user
- `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123456';`
- Re-installed Node.js & npm
- Re-installed MySQL

Comment: you. said " I don't know why, it solve temporarily to reinstall." can you clarify about this? What reinstall temporarily solves the problem?

Comment: modified. I re-installed MySQL. Sorry, that my mistake.

Comment: Can you log in from MySql Workbench?

Comment: Did you said log mean, created log after try to connect from node to MySQL?

Comment: when you tried "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123456';" were you running MySQL with sudo?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to writing where I run on. I run on Window.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your account doesn't have permission to connect to the database.

The command you is GRANT privileges, however, you need the password hash of your account.

to get the password hash of your account run

```
USE mysql;
SELECT Password FROM user WHERE User = 'your Username';
```

Then pipe that output into the password hash section of this command

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `your Username`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'your password hash' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

The % character is a wildcard so it will allow you to connect to the database from any IP address. For added security, you can restrict that to only your IP addresses

hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your solution. That solute error partially. More accurately says, I find other solution thanks to your solution. even if tried your solution, "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" connection is still happen error. but create new user(host "%"), and input my IP address in node, then error is disappear. I think something problem when use "localhost"...

Comment: Would you know other solution? I think Using IP is not solution in my problem